# IndexError: list index out of range, problems when doing a Dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary, split, index-error

I have the following problem: I want to split a string and then generate a list, and then generate a dictionary. But I still get the Error IndexError. Could it be possible that I need to check if certain values do not exist?.

```
result=spawner.catchMumps(iterable=statement,cwd=None)

List1=result.split('^')

for x in List1:
 List2=x.split(',')
 #print List2[2]
 Dic[List2[0]]={
    'class':List2[1],
    'firstname':List2[2],
    'lastname':List2[3],
    'mf':List2[4],
 }
```

result

```
,^e:eind:77942,class:,firstname:,lastname:,mf:,^e:eind:77942,class:,firstname:,lastname:,mf:,^e:eind:77943,class:eind-jg13,firstname:Noah,lastname:Smits,mf:M,^e:eind:77943,class:eind-jg13,firstname:Noah,lastname:Smits,mf:M,^e:eind:77944,class:eind-comf-jaar,firstname:Hemshikha,lastname:Saini,mf:F,^e:eind:77944,class:eind-comf-jaar,firstname:Hemshikha,lastname:Saini,mf:F,^e:eind:77945,class:eind-budg,firstname:Cheryl,lastname:Vriese,mf:F,^e:eind:77945,class:eind-budg,firstname:Cheryl,lastname:Vriese,mf:F,^e:eind:77946,class:,firstname:,lastname:,mf:,^e:eind:77946,class:,firstname:,lastname:,mf:,^e:eind:77947,class:,firstname:,lastname:,mf:,^e:eind:77947,class:,firstname:,lastname:,mf:,^e:eind:77948,class:,firstname:,lastname:,mf:,^e:eind:77948,class:,firstname:,lastname:,mf:,^e:eind:77949,class:,firstname:,lastname:,mf:,^e:eind:77949,class:,firstname:,lastname:,mf:,^e:eind:77950,class:,firstname:,lastname:,mf:,^e:eind:77950,class:,firstname:,lastname:,mf:,^e:eind:77951,class:eind-adm,firstname:Yyy,lastname:Xxxxx,mf:,^e:eind:77951,class:eind-adm,firstname:Yyy,lastname:Xxxxx,mf:,^
```

The Error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "lucho_new_version.py", line 28, in <module>
    'class':List2[1],
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: What exactly is the full error message?

Comment: I've modified my question with the full error message

Comment: So the problem is that `List2` has less than 2 items.

Comment: I don't think so because when I do print List2[2] in the for loop, I get the lastname value

Comment: @LucianoMuratore: There are some entries in the result which are empty ,hence you are getting the index error. You can add print statements to see the outputs.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
List1=b.split('^')
dict_list=[]
for x in List1:
  List2=x.split(',')
  if len(List2) == 6: # <- This eliminates the entries which don't have the data 
        v = {'class':List2[1],
            'firstname':List2[2],
            'lastname':List2[3],
            'mf':List2[4]}
        dict_list.append(v)
```

Comment: By the way, I just write if len(List2) ==6 before Dic[List2[0]]. And it worked. Thanks.